# React axios: Post & Get запросы

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Добрый день, есть axios функции:

получение данных:

```
export function getSidebar() {
    return axios.get('sidebar', {headers: authToken})
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}
```

отправка данных:

```
export function postSidebar(item) {
    return axios.request({
        url: "sidebar/item/add?itemId="+item,
        method: "post",
        baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api/",
        headers: authToken
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.item;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

при post запросе (а именно при нажатие на клик) отправляется item из списка существующих, но при этом функция `getSidebar()` не обновляется и выводит только старые данные. Но при рефреше страницы данные обновляются и выводятся как следует.

Как сделать так что-бы по клику данные которые я отправляю post запросом сразу выводились в моем списке item'ов? Можно сказать что-бы оно обновляло мой `getSidebar()`

Comment: Ну сделай `call` метода `getSlider` в `.then` пост запроса

Comment: сделал `call` метод, оно вроде начало обновлять `sidebar`, но сам блок где выводятся данные мне не обновляет. Т.е. новые данные получаю вроде как, но они не выводятся.

Comment: А вы где и как вообще делаете парсинг новых данных?

Comment: Новых данных, которые появляются после клика? Не как, вот и спрашиваю как это сделать)

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего из-за асинхронности ваши данные не успевают обновиться

Можно передать в функции callback'и, срабатывающие при удачном получении данных

для запроса данных:

```
export function getSidebar(onLoadCallback) {
    return axios.get('sidebar', {headers: authToken})
        .then(response => {
            onLoadCallback(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}
```

для отправки данных:

```
export function postSidebar(item, onSaveCallback) {
    return axios.request({
        url: "sidebar/item/add?itemId="+item,
        method: "post",
        baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api/",
        headers: authToken
    })
    .then(response => {
        onSaveCallback(response.item);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

и, например, если у вас есть обработчики нажатия кнопок "загрузить" и "сохранить"

```
onLoadClick = () => {
    getSidebar(this.onLoad);
}

onSaveClick = (item) => {
    postSidebar(item, this.onSave);
}
```

и написать сами обработчики

```
onLoad = (data) => {
    // какие-то действия с полученными данными
    this.setState({data: data});
}

onSave = (saveResult) => {
    // какие-то действия с полученными данными
    this.setState({saveResult: saveResult});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну если вам нужно диспатчить один экшн после выполнения другого экшна в react/redux  с помощью axios - можно вызывать `getSidebar` в методе componentWillReceiveProps вашего компонента, когда изменятся nextProps, которые, в свою очередь, содержат response.item.

А можно воспользоваться redux-saga, которая создана для подобной логики, тогда весь код будет выглядеть примерно так:

`yield take('POST_SIDEBAR_SUCCESS')
 yield put(getSidebar())`